# How to integrate Amazon Game Circle using Ant?

Tags: java, android, ant, kindle-fire

I have an Android game that is compiled using Ant and I try to integrate it
with Amazon Game Circle. My project and GameCircleSDK look similar in
structure: both contain `jni/`, `libs/`, `res/` and other standard directories
for Android. To integrate Game Circle, [Amazon's documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/gamecircle/docs/initialize-android#Step%201.%20Get%20the%20GameCircle%20Library%20and%20Include%20it%20in%20Your%20Workspace) only touches Eclipse and instructs to
**include Game Circle in the workspace** and add it as a **dependency**.

What is the equivalent for this in Ant? I would like to keep Game Circle out
of my source tree and still compile against it, get all JARs and resources.

The `build.xml` and the rest of the build files I currently use are the default ones generated by `android create project`. I'm posting it here for reference (stripped down the default comments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Game" default="help">
    <property file="local.properties" />
    <property file="ant.properties" />

    <property environment="env" />
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
    </condition>
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing."
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />

    <import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
</project>
```

Comment: I'm not an ant expert, but it might be helpful to post your build XML here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

1. Add the the SDK as a reference in `project.properties`. The path must be relative.

   ```
   android.library.reference.1=../../relative/path/to/gamecircle
   ```
2. Add a `build.xml` to GameCircle by running `android update lib-project -p /path/to/gamecircle`.